# Adding existing C# project to Asp.net Web Api project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, import

I have created an Asp.Net Web API project and I need to import an existing C# project into this project.

can any one help me how to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean import?
You can add **reference** to other project in Solution Explorer > 'Your Project' > References

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import an existing project to you ASP.Net solution, you can rightclick on the Solution in the Solution Explorer, select 'Add' and click on 'Add existing project'

Hope this helps you